# Bluetooth peripherals without usb dongle

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, mouse

My laptop (Lenovo 15IAU7) has bluetooth connectivity as most of them does. Is it possible to connect peripherals like mouse or keyboard without using the peripherals usb-bluetooth dongle? I want to connect them directly to my laptop without the usb dongle.

Comment: Some peripherals are paired to the dongle at the factory, whether they can be paired to another dongle should be covered in the manual

Comment: Most devices with their own dongle aren’t using Bluetooth to connect - it’s a different frequency / standard, so no. There are some wireless devices that have a dongle *and* also have Bluetooth.